# PNG 24 OK in IE if not using trasnparency?

Tags: internet-explorer, png

Will PNG 24 work fine in older versions of IE if im not using any transparency?

PNG 8 doesn't look as good and jpg has a larger file size. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're happy with IE6 and higher, and you're not wanting any transparency, then you'll be fine.

If you need IE5.5 or lower (please say it isn't true!) or you need transparency in IE6, then you'll have problems.

High-colour PNGs were fully supported at the first attempt in IE6. They had plenty of bugs with it, but there was nothing wrong with their high-colour depth support.

Having said all that, you absolutely must test in all browsers that you want to support. If you're not prepared to test it for yourself in IE6, then frankly, you shouldn't be trying to support IE6 at all.

You can test your site in all versions of IE using a tool like [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).

Answer (score 0):

PNG is supported in IE Versions from IE7 & later. It is not supported in IE6 & earlier. To fix it in IE6 you can use PNG fix fo IE6. Click the link for details: http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

Comment: The link is about transparency, which im not using. So do I need any sort of script? Thanks

Comment: Yes, It so simple. download iepngfix.zip from the given URL. Extract the ZIP file in your PC and open the webpage in browser and follow the steps. You will achieve your goal.

Comment: You can also use this PNGFix : http://labs.unitinteractive.com/unitpngfix.php //This is a different version of PNGFix for IE6

Comment: note that @jdln's question explicitly asked if it works *without* using transparency. IE6 *does* support PNG; it's just the transparency that's broken and needs the ifpngfix scripts.